# Accessing object with specific attribute in list

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

Let's say I have a list of objects that hold employee information:

```
class Employee(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

employees = [Employee('Alice'), 
             Employee('Bob'), 
             Employee('Catherine'), 
             Employee('David')]
```

Each object would have more attributes, and there would be more employees, but this is simplified. Now I want to access the Employee object for Catherine. Is there a pythonic way to get Catherine's object? I know I could store the objects in a dictionary with their name as a key, but that seems redundant.

I could use a list comprehension like `[i for i in employees if i.name=='Catherine']`, but I was wondering if there's something more precise, that can access an employee with a specific, unique attribute without searching all the emplooyees.

Comment: You'd need a different data structure to hold them, like a `dict`. This way, the key could be that unique attribute, like `name`, and the value is the instance

Comment: That's why a `dict` *isn't* redundant; it's supplying the indexing that a list of objects themselves don't have.

Comment: `"I know I could store the objects in a dictionary with their name as a key, but that seems redundant"` much less redundant than having to iterate the entire list every single time

Comment: Yes, the dict approach is really what you want as only this gives you the "access to a specific, unique attribute"

Comment: "I know I could store the objects in a dictionary with their name as a key, but that seems redundant." No, it isn't, not if you don't want to search for your object in a list each time.

Comment: For an analogy, using a dictionary here instead of a list is no more "redundant" than the index at the back of a book, which lists the words used in the book which you are likely to want to look up, alongside the page numbers they appear on. The extra information is "redundant" in the strict sense that if those pages were ripped out of the book, you would be able to reconstruct them from the information in the other pages. But it is not "redundant" in the sense that the index can be used for a purpose that the rest of the pages can't be; efficiently finding the pages a word is used on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is precisely what "next" can be used for, it'll return the first positive result in a list comprehension-esque format. It'll raise a StopIteration exception if none is found. You can add a default by wrapping the comprehension in a paren and providing a second argument as well.

`next(i for i in employees if i.name=='Catherine')`

https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next

Comment: but it will still need to look at every single instance in the list. just use a dict with name as key

Comment: The most efficient method is a `dict` (after all, you can always do `dict.values()` if you need just the values in an arbitrary order). This is the second-most efficient, and acts as a short-circuiting list comprehension. Excellent idea.

Comment: There are times to use iterators, and times to use dictionaries. What if there are duplicate keys and you specifically only care about the first one? Or what if keys are compounds of multiple values? In a smaller data set the O(n) lookup is trivial, and there's no reason not to use this approach.

Comment: The generator makes short-circuiting simpler to implement, but it's still a linear search. (On average, you'll have to check more than half the elements as often as you'll check fewer than half.)

Comment: @OsmosisJonesLoL then have name as key and the value a list of instances. `dict` gives you an O(1) solution vs O(n). no way around it

Comment: Also, OP clearly states `"without searching all the emplooyees."`.

Comment: Nobody is debating the efficiency of using a dictionary over a list in the raw lookup circumstance. Let's say however someone was to have a list already, and only need to perform this lookup once. Converting from a list to a dictionary would already be iterating over the whole list O(n). It really depends very strongly on the use case.

This does short circuit so it doesn't always search all the employees, and OP also clearly stated without using a dictionary.

Comment: @OsmosisJonesLoL no, they did not clearly state without using a dictionary. OP wrote they think it's redundant but it is really not.

Comment: Reason I didn't want to use a dictionary is so that I could look up an employee by name, but so that the name could change if necessary (let's say data entry error) without having the dict key and object attribute mismatch. Dictionary would obviously be the most efficient, no question. Thank you @OsmosisJonesLoL for teaching me about next()

Comment: @OsmosisJonesLoL Is next() more efficient than [comprehension][0]?

Comment: @schwartz721 Compare `d = {name: Employee(name) for name in ['Alice', 'Bo']}` with `d = {'Alice': Employee('Alice'), 'Bob': Employee('Bob')}`. The way you *construct* the `dict` can be considered separately from the `dict` itself.

Comment: @schwartz721 next essentially does the same thing as your comprehension, but it immediately stops when it finds the first element and returns it. If your item is at the end of the list, it is more or less the same as `[comprehension][0]` if it's anywhere else it's better the earlier it is in the list.

Answer (score -3):

Yes you can, it just depends on how you implement the `__eq__` dunder method... this would work

```
class Employee(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def __eq__(self, name):
        return self.name == name


employees = [Employee('Alice'),
             Employee('Bob'),
             Employee('Catherine'),
             Employee('David')]
print("Alice" in employees)
```

This would output

```
True
```

Comment: This still requires iteration over the entire list, it just doesn't look like it from the statement

Comment: OP wants the instance, not `True` or `False`